# matplotib RectangleSelector graphical glitch in Qt5 app

Tags: python, qt, matplotlib, pyside2

I try to use Matplotlib in a Qt5 application and would like to use the RectangleSelector, but depending on the parameter `useblit` I get either graphical glitches or the selector disappears.

However when selecting, I get a weird graphical glitch where the entire plot seems to move to the top-left corner, leaving 1cm at the bottom and right side black (or transparent, as my screenshot showed). What is happening here?

[image]

#### Reproduction

This opens a Qt5 window with a plot and some random data. As soon as you select some data it will - for demonstration - clear the axis and plot something new.

If we set `useblit=False`, The RectangleSelector disappears after the first `ax.clear()`, if we have `useblit=True` we get about 1cm of blackness on the bottom and the right side while selecting (see picture).

```
import sys
import matplotlib
import random
matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')

from PySide2.QtCore import *
from PySide2.QtGui import *
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
#from matplotlib.widgets import SpanSelector
from matplotlib.widgets import RectangleSelector

class Window(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.figure = Figure()
        self.ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)

        # First data
        self.ax.plot([random.random() for _ in range(50)])

        # Embedding plot into Qt
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.canvas)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.x = RectangleSelector(self.ax, self.onselect_xy,
                                   drawtype='box',
                                   useblit=False,     # or True?
                                   rectprops={'alpha':0.5, 'facecolor':'red'},
                                   interactive=True)

        self.canvas.draw()


    def onselect_xy(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.ax.clear()
        self.ax.plot([random.random() for _ in range(50)])
        self.canvas.draw()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Window()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

#### Versions

On macOS 10.13.6 HighSierra, selection from `conda list`:

```
python                    3.7.1                haf84260_7
pyside2                   5.6.0a1          py37h45ccf91_3    conda-forge
matplotlib                3.0.2            py37h54f8f79_0
```

Comment: What version of libraries are you using? in Linux with PySide2 5.12 and matplotlib 3.0.2 works correctly with useblit = True.

Comment: Sorry, forgot about that, edited the question. So `useblit=True` would be the proper way to do it? Also I'll try to get a newer pyside2 version...

Comment: yes, it seems to me that the problem would be caused by its old version of PySide2 (the latest LTS versions with 5.9 and 5.12 so its version is very old)

Comment: Problem is, conda only provides 5.6 and when uninstalling and installing with pip, I get errors, like in this [issue on conda-forge](https://github.com/conda-forge/qt-feedstock/issues/70). Do I need to delete a file called "qt.conf" and install both, matplotlib and pyside2 with pip?

Comment: use a virtualenv and install the packages with pip. I do not use conda.

Comment: I am using a virtualenv. Deleted the old one and reinstalled what I need, thanks! Runs smoothly with 5.12. Sorry for being so blind, assumed conda is always up-to-date^^ Please write that as answer if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be the old version of PySide2, with the latest version working correctly. On the other hand conda does not allow to use the latest versions of PySide2 so you must use a virtualenv and install the packages with pip.